# VIMPDB: missing +clientserver on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, vim, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to install VIMPDB on my macport's VIM distibution (Snow Leopard). (I need vim python debugging)
Since macport's VIM seems to have the +clientserver configuration disabled, and VIMPDB needs it enabled, how should I proceed?

Note: I know that it's possible with MacVim - so it must be possible with vim, as well.

Answer (score 0):

No `clientserver` flag in variants of vim port file.

`/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/editors/vim/Portfile`

I think you can add needed configuration option by hands.

```
variant python26 conflicts python25 python27 python31 description {Enable Python scripting} {
     configure.args-append  --enable-clientserver  --enable-pythoninterp --with-python=${prefix}/bin/python2.6
     ...
}
```